# Should I Have Received Enlightened Badge For this Answer?

Tags: support, badges, enlightened-badge

[python chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179241/python-chaining/2179265#2179265)

Comment: Hoping to get one here too, if the OP decides to accept:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list-in-python/2177607#2177607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the badges have a large delay.

Comment: Fair enough...just wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding how it works.  Thanks for the follow up!

Comment: I'm surprised, though, because I've almost always gotten the Nice Answer and Enlightened badges at the exact same time -- and he's already got the Nice Answer for this one.

Comment: Why do some of the badges have a large delay?

Comment: @andrew, because they only run the script that checks for them every so often.

Answer (score 0):

Did you post your answer before or after the other answer?

If before, then yes, and the badge awarding system is probably just taking it's sweet time.

If after, then no. Sorry, Enlightened is a tough one.

Comment: Yeah my answer was first by about a minute and a half.  I'm patient, really I am.  :)

Comment: I didn't realize that's how it worked, I always thought you got it the first time you had an answer with 10 upvotes that was acccepted.  Learn something new everyday.

Comment: It's okay. There are some badges with far worse award times.

Comment: @Lance - Yeah, the badge wording is really weird because it seems Jeff was afraid of using too many words. Feature request?

Answer (score 0):

I believe deleted answers still count for "firstness", so if someone replied before you did, but then deleted their answer, you won't ever see the Enlightened badge.  Some moderator/10k+ user will have to confirm for you whether there is a deleted answer on this question.

Comment: oh?  hrrm...that (might) suck?

Comment: No deleted answers. No worries AJ.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've gotten the badge when the first answer was deleted.

Comment: Nope - you get the badge if a prior answer is deleted. I have in the past. Of course if the answer is subsequently undeleted your answer no longer qualifies so you won't get the badge the next time you have a qualifying answer.